# How to prevent pycallgraph from entering standard library functions?

Tags: python, profiling

I'm using [pycallgraph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/) from the command line to profile and draw the call graph of a relatively simple program. However, the resulting image includes the internals of standard libraries (threading, json, socket) even though I don't use the -s command line option. Using the -e option to exclude those modules has no effect and using -i results in an empty call graph. I've also tried cProfile, but it only graphs the main thread.

How can I make pycallgraph to only show calls in my code? The current messy result is useless.

*Edit:* I'm using 0.5.1, available via easy_install. Running pycallgraph ./cursesclient.py outputs this: [image: a messy call graph]. As you can see, pycallgraph show the internals of modules json, re, encodings, socket and threading. Re and encodings are never even called directly in my code, but through json and socket, respectively.

Comment: anyways, thanks for pointing me at pycallgraph.

Comment: what version do you use? In 0.5.1 I can make graph with only my functions just calling 'pycallgraph mycode.py', but option '-s' ignores some modules like 'functools'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pycallgraph has an undocumented stop_trace() method that you can use to exclude sections of code.  Something like

```
import pycallgraph
import mycode
import stuff_i_dont_want_to_see

pycallgraph.start_trace()
#Initializations

pycallgraph.stop_trace()
stuff_i_dont_want_to_see()
pycallgraph.start_trace()

mycode.things()
pycallgraph.make_dot_graph('cleaner_graph.png')
```

Is that what you're after?

[source](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2007/02/pycallgraph_010_released.html)

Comment: Typing that pretty much results in what I wanted, but it's tedious to wrap all standard library calls to avoid graphing and profiling them; especially so because according to pycallgraph's command line help it should not graph them by default.However, since it's been almost a month I'll accept your answer in the absence of better alternatives.

Answer (score 14):

Pycallgraph provides filtering capabilities to filter out any module, class or function you would like to exclude from call graph. Following function should be defined before you start the trace and passed to pycallgraph

Example

```
def filtercalls(call_stack, modul, clas, func, full):
    mod_ignore = ['shutil','scipy.optimize','re','os','sys','json']
    func_ignore = ['CustomFunctionName','pdbcall']
    clas_ignore = ['pdb']
    return modul not in mod_ignore and func not in func_ignore and clas not in clas_ignore
```

The pycallgraph trace start is

```
pycallgraph.start_trace(filter_func=filtercalls)
```

This way, any module, class or function you provide in filtercalls will be removed. Please note that many time in standard libraries providing just the module name is not enough. Thus, including numpy in mod_ignore will still result in numpy.core being included

Comment: Should arguably be the correct answer since it does what the OP asked, limiting threading for example may not even be possible without eliminating your own Thread instance as well using the 'correct' answer